# WebRTC ICE-Stun message-integrity attribute

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, hmac, stun, hmacsha1

What do I use for the HMAC-SHA1 key when verifying the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY attribute of STUN Binding Requests from Chrome? (chrome is in the ICE-CONTROLLING role as the SDP offer is from an ICE-LITE peer)

[RFC-5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) states:

> To compute the message integrity for the check, the agent uses the
> remote username fragment and password learned from the SDP from its
> peer.  The local username fragment is known directly by the agent for
> its own candidate.

But it does not state how these are concatenated by the agent to form the HMAC SHA1 key

I have tried different combinations of ice-username:ice-password to form the key, but none seem to be able to generate the same hash as the message integrity attribute in the Binding request from chrome.

Does anyone know how the HMAC key is formed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests for you will be signed with your local ice-pwd and the responses must be signed with it (as described [ħere](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8445#section-7.2.2)).

See [RFC 5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#section-10.1.2) on how to compute the hash.

Comment: Thank you! You actually got me back on the right track as my real problem was that I was using the wrong length at the time of the hashing. It's easy to miss: The length at the time of hashing should only include up the end of the  MESSAGE-INTEGRITY attribute, NOT THE FINGERPRINT!

Comment: yes. Sadly there is no test vector along the lines of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5769 -- in cases like this a concrete example helps a lot

Comment: @PhilippHancke RFC 5389 only supports SHA1 for Message Integrity attribute.  However, a proposed RFC [@ Section 14.6] (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-tram-stunbis-14.html#rfc.section.14.6) supports SHA256.  Is it safe to assume support for SHA1 only in the context of ICE binding request for connectivity checks in WebRTC? I ask because one of the popular opensource STUN/TURN server coturn support SHA256, SHA512 also. I was wondering where that comes from. Again... I am only interested in the context of WebRTC.